# Abort trap 6 in array joining function

Tags: c

I'm trying to join the arrays together using a function. It works somehow but prompts an error abort trap 6. In addition, it also says that I cannot free the allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *join_arrays(unsigned int arr1N, int arr1[], unsigned int arr2N, int arr2[], unsigned int arr3N, int arr3[]) {
  int tableLen = arr1N + arr2N + arr3N;
  printf("%d\n", tableLen);
  int *table = malloc(tableLen * sizeof(int));
  table = arr1;
  printf("%d\n", table[arr1N - 1]);
  for (int i = 0; i < arr2N; i++) {
   table[i + arr1N] = arr2[i];
  }
  printf("%d\n", table[arr1N + arr2N - 1]);
  for (int j = 0; j < arr3N; j++) {
   table[j + arr1N + arr2N] = arr3[j];
  }

  return table;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a1[] = { 89, 53, 98, 5, 5, 49, 95, 9, 54, 59, 59 };
    int a2[] = { 44, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 144, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int a3[] = { 20, 21, 22 };

    int *joined = join_arrays(11, a1, 17, a2, 3, a3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11 + 17 + 3; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", joined[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(joined);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `table = arr1;` is effectively making your program to forget the brand new allocated memory location in the previous line...

Comment: Just beat me to it - you need to copy all 3 of the array's values into `table`.  The assignment does not do a table copy.

Comment: just fyi, you can get the number of elements in your arrays and replace the magic numbers with (for example) `sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0])`

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Problem solved. :)

Comment: It's a tad inconsistent to pass the 3 arrays sizes as `unsigned int` and then sum the sizes into a plain `int`.  Be consistent.  Consider using `size_t` for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to copy all 3 tables, not just the second and third.  The assignment of table is effectively throwing away your dynamic memory pointer:

```
int *join_arrays(unsigned int arr1N, int arr1[], unsigned int arr2N, int arr2[], unsigned int arr3N, int arr3[]) {
  int tableLen = arr1N + arr2N + arr3N;
  printf("%d\n", tableLen);
  int *table = malloc(tableLen * sizeof(int));
  int tableOffset = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < arr1N; i++) {
   table[tableOffset++] = arr1[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arr2N; i++) {
   table[tableOffset++] = arr2[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arr3N; i++) {
   table[tableOffset++] = arr3[i];
  }

  return table;
}
```

I'd also consider returning as a parameter so that the array length could be returned as well.  For higher performance, using `memcpy()` may also help on certain systems, though for such a simple example, the for loops are easier to understand.

Comment: `i`, `tableLen` and `tableOffset` should have type `unsigned int`. A even better choice would be to make all these sizes and index values `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

The function is wrong. At least there is a memory leak. At first the pointer `table` points to the allocated memory but then it is reassigned and points to the first character of the first array passed to the function as argument.

```
int *table = malloc(tableLen * sizeof(int));
table = arr1;
```

So the two loops used in the function try to copy to the first array and as result they access memory beyond the array.

Take into account that it is much better to change the order of the function parameters. At first there should be specified an array and only then its size. Also the arrays should be declared with qualifier `const` and their sizes as having type `size_t`.

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 11, 17, and 3. Usually such a usage is a reason for program bugs.

You could use standard C function `memcpy` instead of the loops.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int * join_arrays( const int a1[], size_t n1, 
                   const int a2[], size_t n2, 
                   const int a3[], size_t n3 ) 
{
    int *joined = malloc( ( n1 + n2 + n3 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( joined != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( joined, a1, n1 * sizeof( int ) );       
        memcpy( joined + n1, a2, n2 * sizeof( int ) );      
        memcpy( joined + n1 + n2, a3, n3 * sizeof( int ) );     
    }

    return joined;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a1[] = { 89, 53, 98, 5, 5, 49, 95, 9, 54, 59, 59 };
    int a2[] = { 44, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 144, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int a3[] = { 20, 21, 22 };

    size_t n1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    size_t n2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );
    size_t n3 = sizeof( a3 ) / sizeof( *a3 );

    int *joined = join_arrays( a1, n1, a2, n2, a3, n3 );

    if ( joined != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, n = n1 + n2 + n3; i < n; i++ ) 
        {
            printf( "%d  ", joined[i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }


    free( joined );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
89  53  98  5  5  49  95  9  54  59  59  44  25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  80  0  144  0  0  0  0  20  21  22
```